# Azure with dynamic IP

Tags: azure

Currently I'm working from home, from private network and have dynamic IP (at the moment it's not possible to get static IP).

We have couple virtual machines, couple other services with Azure and there are IP restrictions setup in Network Security Groups and Firewalls.

Is there possibility to set somehow my 'all-the-time-changing-IP' in only one place, so it could be used in Azure Portal as variable, so I would have to update it only in one place?

Comment: You can configure Network Security Group settings using the [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/powershell-install-configure), see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic). So you could create a script to handle these changes all at once.

Comment: Just like a person below said, you can create some sort of script to do that for you, but there is no real solution apart from that (at this point in time)

Comment: or you can deploy a PFSense VM and start it when you need a VPN connection. That will be cheaper than VPN gateway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Powershell, you can update an NSG.

1. Run the following command to retrieve the existing NSG and store it in a variable:

`$nsg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName <NSG-RG> -Name <NSG-NAME>`

2. Run the following command with the new rule settings:

   ```
   Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg `
   -Name rdp-rule `
   -Description "Allow RDP from single IP" `
   -Access Allow `
   -Protocol TCP `
   -Direction Inbound `
   -Priority 102 `
   -SourceAddressPrefix <YOUR NEW IP> `
   -SourcePortRange 3389`
   -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
   -DestinationPortRange 3389
   ```
3. To save the changes made to the NSG, run the following command:

`Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg`

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-ps#manage-rules

Comment: Finally I used this solution. The answer provided byt @evilSnobu seems to be more clean solution, but as Point-to-site VPN is not 100% free (it's not expensive neither).

Answer (score 1):

Just setup a Point-to-site VPN to the Virtual Network in Azure.
The only prerequisite is having a Route-based (IKEv2/Dynamic) gateway in the VNET.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create

Comment: This looks like better solution but it might generate some costs, not much but still.